# How can I optimize that loop?

Tags: matrix, efficiency

I need to populate a matrix $A_{kl}$, where

$$ k = (m-1)J+n$$
$$ l = (p-1)J+q$$

And

$$m,p = 1, 2, ..., I$$
$$n,q = 1, 2, ..., J$$

Its components are `(mnpq)`. For populate it, I'm using a expensive 4 Do loop

```
Do[
 Do[
  Do[
   Do[
    Print[m, n, p, q];
    k = (m - 1) nC + n;
    l = (p - 1) nC + q;
    If[k <= l, A[[k, l]] = cf[Nfunc, xi, yi, wix, wiy, m, n, p, q], 
     0];
    , {q, 1, J, 1}]
   , {p, 1, I, 1}]
  , {n, 1, J, 1}]
 , {m, 1, I, 1}]
```

Knowing that $A_{kl}$ for a $I=J=2$, its components are `(mnpq)`

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
(1111) & (1112) & (1121) & (1122)\\
   & (1212) & (1221) & (1222)\\
 symm. &        & (2121) & (2122)\\
   &        &        & (2222)\\
\end{bmatrix} $$

Does anyone know a more efficient way to populate it?

Comment: You don't say what the problem is.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, the problem is that for $I\times J$ big, the 4 `Do` loop is very expensive.

Comment: Right, but you do have to fill every entry of the matrix and you have to call `cf` for each one of them. There isn't very much you can do about it -- if $I \times J$ is large, then necessarily it is expensive to fill that matrix. It's not like you're doing redundant work as far as I can see -- though of course I have no idea what `cf` actually does.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, this problem was solved using only one `Do` loop, look up here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221172/how-to-efficiently-populate-a-symmetric-matrix/221175?noredirect=1#comment563041_221175. Anyway, thank you.